# How did Gauss arrived at the formula for the circumference of circle in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: biographical-details

My question refers to Gauss's hyperbolic sine expression for a circle circumference in hyperbolic geometry with constant negative curvature. In particular, what specific conceptual developements it anticipated? I ask that because all derivations of this result that i found are based on something called the hyperbolic plane model, while in other places i read that the hyperbolic plane was an innovation of Poincare and Beltrami, not Gauss. So how did Gauss originally found his result? and did he anticipate much later notions?

And by the way, i'll be glad if i'll get an explanation too for Gauss's result in his letter to Gerling from 1819, which gives a formula for the upper bound of area of a triangle in terms of a certain "constant" - the upper bound of the height of isocele triangle in constant negative curvature hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Perhaps i should emphasis my second question. The sine hyperbolic expression for circumference of circle in hyperbolic geometry can be obtained by by inserting an imaginary radius iR  in the expression for circumference in spherical geometry (which i can derive by myself), so it's not very interesting if Gauss arrived at this formula. But my second question is very interesting since i found no references to explanations of Gauss's 1819 letter to Gerling. I think one cannot arive at the result in this letter  without knowledge of models of the hyperbolic plane.